# An uncaught Exception was encountered Google Login (Codeignitor)

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-signin

Type: ArgumentCountError

Message: Too few arguments to function Google_Client::authenticate(), 0 passed in /home/forulive/public_html/application/libraries/Google.php on line 30 and exactly 1 expected

Filename: /home/forulive/public_html/application/third_party/google-api-client/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Client.php

Line Number: 172

Google.php

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Google{   
    public function __construct(){      
        $this->CI =& get_instance();
        $this->CI->load->database();    
        require APPPATH .'third_party/google-api-client/vendor/autoload.php';
        $application_name       =   $this->CI->db->get_where('config' , array('title'=>'google_application_name'))->row()->value;
        $client_id              =   $this->CI->db->get_where('config' , array('title'=>'google_client_id'))->row()->value;
        $client_secret          =   $this->CI->db->get_where('config' , array('title'=>'google_client_secret'))->row()->value;
        $redirect_uri           =   $this->CI->db->get_where('config' , array('title'=>'google_redirect_uri'))->row()->value;
        $api_key                =   $this->CI->db->get_where('config' , array('title'=>'google_api_key'))->row()->value;
        $this->client = new Google_Client();
        $this->client->setApplicationName($application_name);
        $this->client->setClientId($client_id);
        $this->client->setClientSecret($client_secret);
        $this->client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);
        $this->client->setDeveloperKey($api_key);
        $this->client->addScope('email');
        $this->client->addScope('profile');
        $this->client->setAccessType('online');
        $this->client->setApprovalPrompt('auto');
        //$this->oauth2 = new Google_Oauth2Service($this->client);
    }
    
    public function login_url() {
        return $this->client->createAuthUrl();
    }
    
    public function authenticate() {
        return $this->client->authenticate();
    }
    
    public function getAccessToken() {
        return $this->client->getAccessToken();
    }
    
    public function setAccessToken() {
        return $this->client->setAccessToken();
    }
    
    public function revokeToken() {
        return $this->client->revokeToken();
    }
    
    public function get_user_info($code) {
        //It will Attempt to exchange a code for an valid authentication token.
        $token = $this->client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($_GET["code"]);
        //This condition will check there is any error occur during geting authentication token. If there is no any error occur then it will execute if block of code/
         if(!isset($token['error']))
         {
          //Set the access token used for requests
          $this->client->setAccessToken($token['access_token']);

          //Store "access_token" value in $_SESSION variable for future use.
          //$_SESSION['access_token'] = $token['access_token'];

          //Create Object of Google Service OAuth 2 class
          $google_service = new Google_Service_Oauth2($this->client);

          //Get user profile data from google
          return $google_service->userinfo->get();
        //return $this->oauth2->userinfo->get();
        }
    }
    
}
```

Client.php

[HERE](https://forulive.in/Client.php.zip)
it's so long code so gave like this.

tried so many way but nothing help....I'm new to this if this is duplicate then please guide me to the solved one.

Comment: Apparently `$this->client->authenticate();` requires some arguments/parameters. You sure you are following documentation correctly?

Comment: @arxoft it's inside a radymade script....and now maybe google changed some serverside things and script calling old variables so that it's failing....it was working before.

please tell where I have to change if you know...